# Airplane sound effect

Tags: sound-effects, samples

Anyone know any sites which supply fighter jet recordings for download?

I'm looking for specifics.. RAF/Eurofighter planes.

Comment: Hi Ed. I've got some jet fighter stuff I recorded at an air show. Drop me an email and we'll see if we can sort something out. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Although expensive, [Stephan Schutze's Aircraft Collection](http://www.prosoundeffects.com/the-aviation-collection.html) is the most thorough and high quality collection of airplane recordings I am aware of. Take a look through what it included - I would be surprised if it didn't have what you were after.

Answer (score 1):

Check out John Leonard's Sounds of Flight:
http://www.johnleonard.co.uk/immersive.html

Best

Comment: Hmm, It's awesome and cheap! I love it! Definatly my next library to buy;)